# Pandas: how to apply the series of functions to multiple pairs of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using old population projection data to establish the growth ratio proportion of different cities and then multiply that with the newly updated growth number in order to get the new projection numbers. It may not sound like so, but the idea is extremely easy.

The simplified example I created:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({2010: [100, 110, 120], 2015: [150, 155, 175], 2020: [180, 190, 200], 2025: [200, 210, 220]},
                  index = {'CityA', 'CityB', 'CityC'})
df
```

[image: Beginning]

After that my series of functions is:

```
df['10-15'] = df[2015] - df[2010]
growth = df['10-15'].sum()
df['10-15 ratio'] = df['10-15']/growth

#Real Total growth is calculated from another dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame({2015: 200, 2020:210, 2025: 220}, index = ['real increase'])
df2
```

[image: growth]

```
growth2015 = df2.at['real increase', 2015]

df['New2015'] = df[2010] + growth2015*df['10-15 ratio']
```

Ultimately, this will give me the result I want, the projection adjusted with the newest growth number.

```
df
```

[image: End]

The problem now is that I have do this for every year from 2015 to 2045. I know there must be a way to do this without copying and pasting forever in Python but I just don't know how. How shall I achieve this, build a dictionary or function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, since no one replied I just kept on trying. I figured out how to do it via function. I don't think it's very efficient but it gets the job done. Please add other methods if you can

```
def letstry(n):
    df[str(n-5)+ '-' +str(n)] = df[n] - df[n-5]
    growth = df[str(n-5)+ '-' +str(n)].sum()
    df[str(n-5)+ '-' +str(n)+ 'ratio']  = df[str(n-5)+ '-' +str(n)]/growth
    realg = df2.at['real increase', n]
    df['New' + str(n)] = df[n-5] + realg*df[str(n-5)+ '-' +str(n)+ 'ratio']
    return df

for i in range(2010, 2050, 50):
    letstry(i)
```